# Storage of global variables in recursive function calls in memory

Tags: c, memory, recursion

In recursive functions the local variables in each recursive function call are stored in a stack but what happens if I declare a global variable and use it in the recursive function? How are  global variables handled?

The usual code for an factorial is

```
int fact (int n)
{
  if(n<1) return 1;
      else return (n*fact(n-1));
}
```

While i was reading computer architecture,i studied that local variables are stored in a stack from a higher addresses to lower addresses,heap is for dynamic structures which start from lower addresses and global variables are stored separately.

so i modified it to

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int global=0;

int fact()
{
  if(global<1)return 1;
  else
      return((global--)*fact());
}

main()
{
  int i=0;
  printf("enter the factorial\n");
  scanf("%d",&global);
  i=fact();
  printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

I know something the code is wrong intuitively ,i just modified it to this to check whats gonna happen.the result is segmentation fault Please explain me whats happening here,possibly how the compiler behaves to this?

Comment: There is nothing special about recursive functions. They work exactly the same as non-recursive functions.

Comment: Global variables are stored at the very same memory address during the entire lifetime of the program. Their location doesn't change, regardless of where you are using them from.

Comment: @Mat  I have shared the ARM assembly code for the usual factorial which clearly explains whats happening,If anyone is good with ARM assembly language please explain whats going wrong in the modified code is wrong in terms of ARM assembly language        [link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hyb4mDkoFVx-ZU8rMPZ9fZ58hDHC8QdaFI-ukaYn-YA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are stored in `data segment` whereas local variables(declared and defined in functions) are stored in `stack`. They disappear after the function return. 
You can find the details [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

Comment: Please site your sources, whole parts of this are copy/pasted from  [this](http://books.google.fr/books?id=nMZnyp_zW8AC&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=The+heap+area+begins+at+the+end+of+the+BSS+segment+and+grows+to+larger+addresses+from+there.The+Heap+area+is+managed+by+malloc&source=bl&ots=KaOp6q563h&sig=bAiBadD5F3dfgD__Dgq8QLd9__U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m7pMVMWlDMP6PNDLgKAL&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20heap%20area%20begins%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20BSS%20segment%20and%20grows%20to%20larger%20addresses%20from%20there.The%20Heap%20area%20is%20managed%20by%20malloc&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Storage class decides scope and visibility of the variable. Local variables are of type "auto" hence gets stored in the stack segment. Whereas global and static variables gets stored in data segment. The scope and visibility of local variables is limited inside block or function inside which they are defined. Therefore new set of local variables gets loaded when each time when function is called.In case of global variables there scope remains till lifetime  of program.